# Mongodb group by same value

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm working with Node and Mongoose and I'm really new at it.

Let's say I have the following collection called userposts, route and index.ejs file.

I would like to display all of John's posts (where author is John) on the page authors/john and all of Mary's posts (where author is Mary) on the page authors/mary.

Currently the page authors/mary, for example, displays all the posts in the collection. Could somebody help me?

collection:

```
{
"_id" : 1,
"title" : "title1",
"description" : "description1",
"author": "John",
"link": "john"
}
{
"_id" : 2,
"title" : "title2",
"description" : "description2",
"author": "John",
"link": "john"
}
{
"_id" : 3,
"title" : "title3",
"description" : "description3",
"author": "Mary",
"link": "mary"
}
{
"_id" : 4,
"title" : "title4",
"description" : "description4",
"author": "Mary",
"link": "mary"
}
```

route:

```
router.get("/authors/:link", function(req, res){
    Userposts.find(req.params.author, function(err, allUserposts){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            if(req.xhr) {
                res.json(allUserposts);
            } else {
                res.render("userposts/index", {userposts: allUserposts});
            }
        }
    });
});
```

index.ejs:

```
<% userposts.forEach(function(post){ %>
    <article>
      <h4><%= post.title %></h4>
      <p><%= post.author %></p>
      <p><%= post.description %></p>
    </article>
<% }) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are making the query to get user specific posts, you should mention the author name.

Since in your route, you are using a query,

```
BlogPostModel.find(authorName)
```

The proper syntax should be,

```
BlogPostModel.find({ author: authorName })
```

> While making a MongoDB query, you must follow the key value syntex.

Your final route should be

```
router.get("/authors/:link", function(req, res){
    Userposts.find({ author: req.params.author }, function(err, allUserposts){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            if(req.xhr) {
                res.json(allUserposts);
            } else {
                res.render("userposts/index", {userposts: allUserposts});
            }
        }
    });
});
```

For more, you can check the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you use "Express" as your Node backend framework.

The valueName start with ":" in Express router means values in "req.params", so if you use ":link", you can get this value from "req.params.link". You can get more detail from http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html.

Also if you want to query by author, the right format of mongoose find operation is:

```
Userposts.find({ author: req.params.link })
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers. Yes, I'm using Express. After applying your solutions, it still didn't work the way I wanted it. I ended up getting the current url in my route and putting an if statement into my ejs template. Now it's working. So my final route and index.ejs look like this:

```
router.get("/authors/:link", function(req, res){
    var currentUrl = req.originalUrl;
    Userposts.find({}, function(err, allUserposts){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            if(req.xhr) {
                res.json(allUserposts);
            } else {
                res.render("userposts/index", {userposts: allUserposts, currentUrl: currentUrl});
            }
        }
    });
});

<% userposts.forEach(function(post){ %>
    <% if(post.link === currentUrl) { %>
        <article>
          <h4><%= post.title %></h4>
          <p><%= post.author %></p>
          <p><%= post.description %></p>
        </article>
    <% } %>
<% }) %>
```